# Error in csh script

Tags: csh, tcsh

I'm working with C-Shell, I'm trying to run this script

```
set callsTo = "`cut -d" " -f2 ${1}`"
echo $callsTo
```

cut receives data from the file which is the first parameter:

```
> ./myscript data
```

I need only second field from every row: `-f2`.

After that I want to check if the data was stored, but I receive or an error unmatched . or empty row.  What is wrong with my script?

Also when I'm using `#! /bin/tcsh -f` I receive this message

```
 tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes don't nest like that.

Try this:

```
set callsTo = "`cut -d' ' -f2 ${1}`"
```

> Also when I'm using #! /bin/tcsh -f I receive this message
>
> tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ]

That's odd.  Is it possible there's a stray character after the `-f`, perhaps a `'\r'` character from a Windows-style line ending?  What is the output of `head -1 *foo*.tcsh | od -c`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know tcsh but shouldn't this line

```
set callsTo = "`cut -d" " -f2 ${1}`"
```

be

```
set callsTo = `cut -d" " -f2 ${1}`?
```

In bash I would have done this way:

```
callsTo=`cut -d' ' -f2 $1`?
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `callsTo=$(cut -d' ' -f2 "$1")` in bash.  `$()` is more predictable for users and nests better, compared to backticks.  I don't know the equivalent csh, but looking for it might help.

Comment: csh has no `$(...)` syntax; it only has backticks.

Answer (score 0):

set filename=`echo ${1}|cut -f1 -d'#'`
echo $filename
Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
set callsTo = "`cut -d"\"" "\"" -f2 ${1}`"
```

This is how to escape double quotes.

The same applies to the dollar symbol, to prevent variable expansion:

```
echo ""\$"test is not variable-expanded."
```